# Facebook API retrieving friends list in swift

Tags: xcode, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

Why is this giving me a error?

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Am I using the wrong `valueForKey` `String`? I want to get the list of friends. (There are friends because when I print result it shows them)

```
let fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/friends", parameters: nil);
fbRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
            let userName : NSArray = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSArray
        print("Friends are : \(result)")

    } else {

        print("Error Getting Friends \(error)");

    }
    }
```

Comment: From what I remember,  you can only get a list of friends that are currently using the app - I'm not sure what the end point is for that.

Comment: Yup you can only get friends which are using your app already. You are probably getting a nil array because maybe none of your friends are using that app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
let fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/friends", parameters: nil);
fbRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
       if let userNameArray : NSArray = result.valueForKey("data") as! NSArray
       {
          var i:Int = 0
          for i;i<userNameArray.count ; i++
          {
             print(userNameArray[i].valueForKey("name"))
          }      

       } else {

        print("Error Getting Friends \(error)");

      }
    }
```